# how to mapping/dispatcher the Django urls?

Tags: django, url, mapping, dispatcher

I'm trying to make some Maps...
to use in market.

so i try to use Django, Python.
but there are some problems related to url mapping.

here's the problem.

jeobjeom_code = c[5] = pk = SAF11050

i want to make some links like 'RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail/SAF11050'
but didn't work.

if jeobjeom_code is only int, it works!
but if jeobjeom_code is string, didn't work at all.

i guess
c[5] using is wrong... but i don't know how to fix it...

NoReverseMatch at /Maps_DaeLi_PanMae
Reverse for 'RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 'c[5]'}' not found.

-models.py

```
class RawSomaeMaejangInfo(models.Model):
    jeobjeom_code = models.CharField(db_column='JeobJeom_Code', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    latitude = models.CharField(db_column='Latitude', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    longitude = models.CharField(db_column='Longitude', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

-urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail/<int=pk>', views.RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail, name='RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail'),
```

-Maps_DaeLi_PanMae.html

```
                      var tmpl = '<div style="font-family: dotum, arial, sans-serif;font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;margin-bottom: 5px;">#{title}</div>' +
                          '<table style="border-spacing: 2px; border:s 0px"><tbody><tr>' +
                          '<tr><td style="color:#767676;padding-right:12px">check</td>' +
                          '<td><a href="{% url 'RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail' pk='c[5]' %}" >link</a></td>' +
```

-views.py

```
def Maps_DaeLi_PanMae(request):
    Maps_DaeLiJeom_list = RawSomaeMaejangInfo.objects.all()
    context = {"Maps_DaeLiJeom_list":Maps_DaeLiJeom_list}
    return render(request, 'app/Maps_DaeLi_PanMae.html', {"Maps_DaeLiJeom_list":Maps_DaeLiJeom_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't understand what is the purpose of **c[5]**.. I found two errors in your code those might be causing the issue..

Your url pattern should be like this..

```
path('RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail/<int:pk>/', views.RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail, name='RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail'),
```

In template, you have loop through the **Maps_DaeLiJeom_list**..

```
{% for Maps_DaeLiJeom in Maps_DaeLiJeom_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'RAW_SoMae_MaeJang_Info_detail' pk=Maps_DaeLiJeom.pk %}" >link</a>
{% endfor %}
```